# Why is this code inserting more than one row in the database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

I have this code that adds Product to Products table in the database but it is adding more than one row.

Here's the code:

```
public int addProduct(Products product, String supplierName) {

    //find a product
    String checkAllProducts = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name = ?";

    //Insert product and supplier id where supplier exist in suppliers table sql statement
    String insertSql = "INSERT INTO products (product_name, product_type, supplier_id, number_of_stocks, price_per_unit, packaging_type) SELECT ?,?,suppliers.supplier_id,?,?,? FROM  suppliers WHERE suppliers.supplier_name = ?";

    //Get connection
    Connection conn = DbUtil.getConnection();

    //Resultset for checking existing products
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    int inserted = 0;

    try {

        //Prepare check all products statement
        allProducts = conn.prepareStatement(checkAllProducts);
        allProducts.setString(1, product.getProductName());
        resultSet = allProducts.executeQuery();

        //If doesn't exist in products table
        if (!resultSet.next()) {
            //Prepare insert statement
            addProduct = conn.prepareStatement(insertSql);
            //Get product parameter's data
            addProduct.setString(1, product.getProductName());
            addProduct.setString(2, product.getProductType());
            addProduct.setInt(3, product.getNumberOfStocks());
            addProduct.setBigDecimal(4, product.getPricePerUnit());
            addProduct.setString(5, product.getPackagingType());
            addProduct.setString(6, supplierName);

            //Confirm insert
            int confirmation = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to insert this product?", "Insert Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            if (confirmation == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                //execute insert
                inserted = addProduct.executeUpdate();
            }

        }//Else don't insert and show error messages.
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product already exists.", "Invalid insert.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProductDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        DbUtil.close(conn, allProducts, resultSet);
        DbUtil.close(conn, addProduct, resultSet);
    }

    return inserted;
}
```

As you can see in the code above, I'm checking if a product doesn't exist in the table then insert with confirmation. It's successfully adding but it's adding more than one row. For example, assume that I have initialised the productDao object and I test it out in this way: `productDAO.addProduct(new Products("Hotdogs", "Full", 55, new BigDecimal(0.30), "Box"), "Wing Yip");`. After doing that, it inserted 14 of these as you can see in the image's link below;

[14 Duplicate Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkPbU.png)

Does anyone know why this is happening? Please let me know thanks.

Comment: Your insert is inserting the results of a `select` statement - maybe you are not meaning to do this?  And this `select` is not the same `select` as you are checking

Comment: @Scary Wombat Is it? Well, I want to insert the `supplier_id` and what you said is not really my intention. Is my statement wrong?

Comment: try running `SELECT ?,?,suppliers.supplier_id,?,?,? FROM products, suppliers WHERE products.supplier_id = suppliers.supplier_id AND suppliers.supplier_name = ?";` separately and see what results you get

Comment: As a separate String variable? If so, I will try...

Comment: You should remove the initial testing SELECT and use ON DUPLICATE IGNORE in the INSERT statement. Your way you have a timing-window problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of your insert statement is a select statement:

```
SELECT
    ?, ?,
    suppliers.supplier_id,
    ?, ?, ? 
FROM products, suppliers
WHERE 
    products.supplier_id = suppliers.supplier_id 
    AND suppliers.supplier_name = ?
```

This has the ability to select all records that have that supplier name and which appear in both tables. Evidently that supplier has 14 products, so that is how many new records are inserted.

To fix this remove the implicit `JOIN`. It isn't needed for the `supplier_id` lookup.

```
INSERT INTO products (
    product_name, 
    product_type,
    supplier_id,
    number_of_stocks,
    price_per_unit, 
    packaging_type
) SELECT 
    ?, ?,
    suppliers.supplier_id,
    ?, ?, ?
FROM suppliers
WHERE suppliers.supplier_name = ?
```

Comment: So my statement was right but with added `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Correct. Another way to solve it is to add `DISTINCT suppliers.supplier_id`, but that makes the query do more work than it needs to.

Comment: I like your answer. Thank you so much. I am really trying to do INSERT INTO SELECT statements to minimise the code. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Why do you have `products.supplier_id = suppliers.supplier_id`? It seems like that part isn't needed. Wouldn't that only allow you to insert records with a supplier that already exists in the table?

Comment: That was to check if it's the same and I think you're right.

Comment: I've made edits, because removing that join should make it so that it always returns 1 record. Just make sure that the `supplier_name` is marked `UNIQUE` and for better performance you should add an index to `supplier_name`.

Comment: Thanks again for your tips. ATM, it is not set as unique I will do that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Scary Wombat and @4castle for the help. What I did now is to create a separate statement and added more code as you can see below.

```
//find supplier
String checkSupplierQuery = "SELECT products.supplier_id FROM products, suppliers WHERE products.supplier_id = suppliers.supplier_id AND suppliers.supplier_name = ? ";

//Prepare check supplier statement
PreparedStatement checkSupplier = conn.prepareStatement(checkSupplierQuery);
checkSupplier.setString(1, supplierName);
resultSet = checkSupplier.executeQuery();

String supplier = "";
while (resultSet.next()) {
  supplier = resultSet.getString("products.supplier_id");
}
```

This solved my problem but I'm trying with `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement which it didn't work as I expected. Thanks again for those who helped me. :-)